# Element.querySelector is undefined

Tags: javascript, dom

Why does this code throw an error in the console reading `TypeError: pizzaBox.querySelector is not a function. (In 'pizzaBox.querySelector('h6')', 'pizzaBox.querySelector' is undefined)`?

```
function addToppingsToAll (toppings)
{
    var pizzaBoxHolder = document.getElementById("PizzaBoxHolder");
    var PizzaBoxList   = pizzaBoxHolder.childNodes;
    for ( var i = 0 ; i < pizzaBoxList.length ; i++ )
    {
        var pizzaBox            = pizzaBoxList[i];
        toppingList             = pizzaBox.querySelector('h6');
        toppingList.textContent = "You have " + toppings " on your pizza";
    }
}
```

Comment: Replace `childNodes` with `children` and see if that solves it ?

Comment: What is `lineBoxList`? I don't see that defined anywhere. Shouldn't that be `pizzaBoxList`? Edit: also you should be initialising your index variable in the for loop, `var i = 0`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are at least three isssues in your code:

1. You are probably iterating through some text nodes which don't have a `.querySelector()` method.
2. You are not initializing your `for` loop iteration variable `i`
3. You have an undeclared variable `lineBoxList` you are attempting to use.

You can simplify things by just using `.querySelectorAll()` and letting the selector do more of the work for you.

```
function addToppingsToAll (toppings) {
    var toppingItems = document.querySelectorAll("#PizzaBoxHolder h6");
    for (var i = 0; i < toppingItems.length; i++) {
        toppingItems[i].textContent = "You have " + toppings " on your pizza";
    }
}
```

Comment: This is helpful, but now ToppingItems.length in the for loop declaration doesn't work. Is there a way to solve that?

Comment: @BillBllson - Did you switch to `.querySelectorAll()` as my code shows?  It returns a `nodeList` which has a `.length` property (it's an array-like object).  Also, check your capitalization.  I'm using `toppingItems` and `toppingItems.length`.

Comment: I did all of this. Upon revision I realize there is no problem with the for loop, but `toppingItems.length` returns 0. If it matters, PizzaBoxHolder is an HTML div containing at least 1 div within itself, and each inner div has exactly 1 h6 in it, so the h6's are not direct children of PizzaBoxHolder.

Comment: @BillBllson - please add the relevant HTML to your question and I will post a working jsFiddle link to show you how the code can work.  As it is, I can't see the exact code you're using or the HTML you have, so I'm flying blind as to what you are doing wrong.  It does not matter that the `h6` elements are children of children.

Answer (score 4):

`querySelector` is a method that appears on HTML Element Nodes. One or more of the `childNodes` must be some kind of node that is not an Element (such as Text Nodes or Comment Nodes).

This is probably most easily resolved with:

```
var PizzaBoxList   = document.querySelector("#PizzaBoxHolder > *");
```